# Craft 3 Multisite: Template not found

Tags: localization, craft3, multi-site

I'm trying to set up a multisite with Craft 3, and the client wants a set up with URLs that look like `foo.client.com`, with `foo.client.com/2018` and `foo.client.com/2019`. Right now, my `index.php` file looks like this:

```
switch(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1]) {
  case '2018':
    define('CRAFT_SITE', 'twentyEighteen');
    break;
  default:
    define('CRAFT_SITE', 'default');
}
```

This correctly changes the site if I go to `/2018`, but the problem is that Craft is looking for templates at `templates/2018/xx/xx` instead of `templates/xx/xx`.. So when I go to `foo.client.com/2018` I get:

**Template not found: 2018**

In the back-end I have the `twentyEighteen` site defined and the site base URL is set to `http://foo.client.com/2018/`.

I know that this should work because they even use `/en` and `/nl` as examples in the [Craft 2 Localization Guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide), and Craft 3 multisites work similarly.